# Calculating exact p-values from a Pearson's correlation test (manually or in R)

Tags: r, p-value, pearson-correlation

(What I believe is) a very simple question. I have just performed a Pearson's correlation test in R, and I'd like to know the exact p-value. However, the p-value is so small R (or tdist in Excel, or any other online calculate-it software) tells me the p-value is <2.2e-16 or 0. I suspect it has something to do with the large number of observations I have (n = 11001).

Here's the output I get from running a pairwise correlation

> cor.test(mets$s_M48153,mets$s_M48152)

```
             Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  mets$s_M48153 and mets$s_M48152
t = 88.401, df = 10999, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.6334378 0.6552908
sample estimates:
  cor 
0.6444959
```

"cor.test(mets$s_M48153,mets$s_M48152)$p.value" also gives me a p-value of 0.

Because of this, I'd like to manually calculate the exact p-value using the t-statistic and degrees of freedom, but I can't find the formula anywhere. Does anyone know the formula, or can tell me how to extract exact p-values from R (if possible)?

Comment: Someone knows the formula (just google it). To extract with R: `cor.test(mets$s_M48153,mets$s_M48152)[["p.value"]]`

Comment: I have tried googling, but to no avail (otherwise I wouldn't ask here!). I just tried your code as well, but it still returns 0. :(

Comment: you can look at the code `stats:::cor.test.default`to see what formula is used

Comment: Is it 0 or is it really-close to 0? Try an inequality test, `... > 0`. If it is `TRUE`, then the "0" you see is just R's representation of it based on several display options (e.g., `digits`, `scipen`).

Comment: You are getting a zero because the result is considered a zero by your computer (it's missing the values after the 16th decimal place). If you run `.Machine$double.eps` you will probably obtain a value close close to 2.2e-16 as well. Is there a reason why you wish to report a p-value smaller than e-16?

Comment: Good point, @NewUser: traditionally, p-values below 0.05 were considered sufficient. That position [is changing](https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.2016.1154108), but even with large `n` sample sizes, I suggest that a p-value 16 digits right of zero should suffice. To do any better, you'll likely need the [`bit64`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/index.html) package and calculate things manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions and advice, and sorry for not replying sooner. I've been juggling a few things around until recently. However, I did ask a statistician within my department about this, and he agreed with what r2evans said. If the p-value is smaller than 10^-16, there's little point in reporting an 'exact' value, since the point is that there is strong evidence that the result differs from the null hypothesis.

One case when p-values might be important is when you want to rank by order of significance, but you could get around this by using z-scores to rank instead.

To address the original question, I defer to this guide, which I found long after posting this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315311/how-to-find-p-value-using-estimate-and-standard-error.